# Error: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Following is my Simple JSON code which is showing the error:
"ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.5.1/getcommands.txt").read()
print data
d = json.loads(data)
print d
```

Please help me as am new to this.

My getcommands.txt contains following data and its also the output for print data:
GetLocation
Shutdown
Reboot
CleanData

Comment: It means the String is not valid JSON. try printing the string.

Comment: How should we help if you don't provide `get commands.txt`? `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` obviously means that your `data` is not valid  `JSON`.

Comment: If in doubt, if the data is valid JSON, you can post the contents that you fetch to services like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: What is the result of `print data`? Can you edit your question to include it please?

Answer (score 0):

> My getcommands.txt contains following data and its also the output for print data: GetLocation Shutdown Reboot CleanData

That's very obviously not [valid JSON](http://www.json.org).